# Efficient simultaneous permutation of two large matrices in R

Tags: r, permutation

I have two objects, both matrices:

```
pop1[,1:5]
>            8:31:+    8:91:+     8:106:+      8:133:+        8:137:+
> [1,]        42        39          36           41              39
> [2,]        26        24          19           25              23
> [3,]        24        25          22           26              22
> [4,]         4         4           2            4               4
> [5,]        34        24          33           33              33
> [6,]        14        14          10           14              12

pop2[,1:5]
>            8:31:+    8:91:+     8:106:+      8:133:+        8:137:+
> [1,]        45        36          36           41              35
> [2,]        26        14          19           25              23
> [3,]        14        25          21           23              20
> [4,]         4         4           2            2               6
> [5,]        29        29          30           31              32
> [6,]        14        17           9           16              10
```

I want to permutate each column. Easy enough, e.g. for pop1:

```
pop1.permuted <- do.call('cbind', lapply(as.data.frame(pop1[,1:5]), sample))
```

The problem is that I need to shuffle each column of the two matrices in the same way. For example (made up values):

```
pop1[,1:2]
>            8:31:+    8:91:+     
> [1,]         1         7         
> [2,]         2         8          
> [3,]         3         9          
> [4,]         4        10           
> [5,]         5        11          
> [6,]         6        12          

pop2[,1:2]
>            8:31:+    8:91:+     
> [1,]         1         7         
> [2,]         2         8          
> [3,]         3         9          
> [4,]         4        10           
> [5,]         5        11          
> [6,]         6        12
```

After permuting it should look like this:

```
pop1[,1:2]
>            8:31:+    8:91:+     
> [1,]         1        11         
> [2,]         5        12          
> [3,]         6         8          
> [4,]         2         9
> [5,]         3        10        
> [6,]         4         7          

pop2[,1:2]      
>            8:31:+    8:91:+     
> [1,]         1        11         
> [2,]         5        12          
> [3,]         6         8          
> [4,]         2         9
> [5,]         3        10        
> [6,]         4         7
```

I could loop though the columns but there are 106,770 columns, so looping though all of them 999 (the number of times I want to shuffle both matrices) times would take days or weeks.

What I came up with so far is this:

```
pop1.per <- pop1
pop2.per <- pop2

psi.p=list()
for (i in 1:999){ 
  order <- sample(1:6)
  pop1.per <- do.call('cbind',lapply(pop1.per, 
                                              function(x){x=x[order]
                                                          return(x)}))
  pop2.per <- do.call('cbind',lapply(pop2.per, 
                                              function(x){x=x[order]
                                                          return(x)}))
  psi.p[[i]] <- get.all.psi(pop1.per, pop2.per)         # the calculation I make with the matrices (doesn't really matter)
}
```

The problem is that with this code each column is rearranged according to the 'order' object, but I want a new order for each column.

So, I am stuck here and would appreciate some input. Thank you.

**Update:**

I figured that it should work when I use the same seed each time and it it runs quite fast this way:

```
pop1.per <- pop1
pop2.per <- pop2
col.sample <- function(x, s){s=s+1; set.seed(s); sample(x)}

psi.p=list()
for (i in 1:999){
  seed <- sample(seq(1000,9999,4),1)
  pop1.per <- sapply(1:ncol(pop1.per), function(cl) col.sample(x= pop1.per[,cl], s=round(seed*cl)))
  pop2.per <- sapply(1:ncol(pop2.per), function(cl) col.sample(x= pop2.per[,cl], s=round(seed*cl)))

  psi.p[[i]] <- get.all.psi(pop1.per, pop2.per)         # the calculation I make with the matrices (doesn't really matter)
}
```

The answer from Julian_Hn seems to work as well, but I did not try (thanks for your answer anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can pregenerate the permutations and then separately apply them to the matrices:

```
m1 <- matrix(1:50,ncol=5)

m2 <- m1 + 1000

permutations <- replicate(ncol(m1),sample(nrow(m1)))


m1.perm <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(permutations)),function(i) m1[permutations[,i],i])
m2.perm <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(permutations)),function(i) m2[permutations[,i],i])

m1.perm
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    9   12   24   32   48
 [2,]    4   14   22   31   47
 [3,]    3   20   23   39   43
 [4,]    7   15   27   37   49
 [5,]    2   17   21   34   46
 [6,]    1   16   30   33   44
 [7,]    5   11   25   40   41
 [8,]   10   13   28   36   45
 [9,]    8   19   29   38   42
[10,]    6   18   26   35   50


m2.perm
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,] 1009 1012 1024 1032 1048
 [2,] 1004 1014 1022 1031 1047
 [3,] 1003 1020 1023 1039 1043
 [4,] 1007 1015 1027 1037 1049
 [5,] 1002 1017 1021 1034 1046
 [6,] 1001 1016 1030 1033 1044
 [7,] 1005 1011 1025 1040 1041
 [8,] 1010 1013 1028 1036 1045
 [9,] 1008 1019 1029 1038 1042
[10,] 1006 1018 1026 1035 1050
```